# How to make pipenv install virtual environment in project folder on Windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I want to fully understand how `pipenv` works. 
I created my project and would like virtual environment also be in same project folder. 
However pipenv installs virtual environment in `C:\Users\username\.virtualenvs`.

[image]

With that, if I change the name or location of my project path, the virtual environment will be lost.

So how can I install virtual environment inside project folder?
I read about setting variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` but I did not understand where and how should I do that using Powershell in windows.

Can somebody advise?

Answer (score 6):

Create a .venv folder in your project root. Then run:

```
pipenv shell
```

Obviously run that from a terminal session in your project root. Pipenv should check to see if there is an empty .venv and if it finds one it should blow your virtual environment into that.

Comment: This works. Interestingly, the docs advice [here](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-virtual-environment-location) and [here](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#virtualenv-mapping-caveat) to set `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`. I tested that with Powershell, but it seemed to have zero effect. Even according to the source code ([pipenv\project.py](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/62a6a0e7703bd5f4112dcbe5972f540259a54182/pipenv/project.py#L261)) setting `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` or creating `project/.venv` should be equivalent.

Comment: @NikoFohr So, what is the correct way on PowerShell? I did SET the variable and nothing changed. It still creates the VENV inside Users/User/.VirtualEnvs ... :(

Answer (score 0):

You should add `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` to the Windows 10 User variable

Check out this for step by step process [link](https://gist.github.com/Saketh-Chandra/28ac93aca0afb8a627ef66edaf575b0d) where I mentioned the process with images

if you can't open: https://gist.github.com/Saketh-Chandra/28ac93aca0afb8a627ef66edaf575b0d

Comment: or `SET PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was just testing here, and the following things did'nt work:

- set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
- Creating .venv folder and running `pipenv shell` did work, sort of, but since, in theory, this is manual work instead of automating a Python environment, I did'nt consider it as a solution.

The actual solution for me was:

Just Opened PowerShell and typed `$env:PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` with a PowerShell Terminal open inside the project folder, and executed `pipenv install`. This worked and stopped creating .venvs on other User Profile folder.

For me this was the better approach since I am trying to automate this install using Docker Composer.

[image: PowerShell with VENV inside my Project.]

TL;DR;

```
cd <project_folder>
$env:PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
pipenv install
```