# pipenv creating Pipfile & Pipfile.lock in one-up directory

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am trying to install `Django` using `pipenv`. The command used is

```
pipenv install django~=3.1.0
```

The command is issued in django folder. The command creates files `PipFile and Pipfile.lock` on `Desktop` folder instead of `Desktop/django` folder.

How to create PipFile and Pipfile.lock in django folder instead of Desktop folder?

Operating system is Windows 10 and python in 3.7.

Comment: Before starting the project, we have to activate virtual environment using command ```pipenv shell``` in root folder(django in your case). Then run ```pipenv install django```, it will create Pipfile at correct location.

Comment: You can view the answer here. This might work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308777/how-to-make-pipenv-install-virtual-environment-in-project-folder-on-windows-10